# How to setup views in game maker studio?

Tags: game-maker, gml

[How do I get rid of these black bars?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iFOv.png)

I've looked around and people say how to get rid of them but don't show how its done. This is what I have in my character Creation event.

```
`///Camera

view_wview[1]=611;//set wiew width
view_hview[1]=611;//set view height
view_enabled[1] = true;//enable view
view_visible[1] = true;//make visible
view_hborder[1]=1920;//set horizontal border for object
view_vborder[1]=1080;//set vertical border
view_object[1]=obj_Medic;//set object to follow
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could widen your view to fit your screen or set your game to fit the screen in the display options menu as shown: [image]

The stretching may cause distortions as you can see from my example, an unfinished project I made a while back (a RoTMG simulator).

**Window:**
[image]

**Stretched Fullscreen:**
[image]

Comment: I use GM:S not GM8

Comment: @RubbishAmbush This is GM:Studios. I have a custom color look set.

Comment: how do I make the aspect ratio 16:9?